# Problems with public key - trying to upgrade Lubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

Tags: upgrade, lubuntu

I am trying to upgrade my 18.04.6 LTS server, but am unable to get updates due to an issue with a public key. When I try to resolve the public key issue I get a failure.
Any ideas?

```
myuser@myuser-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for myuser: 
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/bit-team/stable/ubuntu yakkety InRelease
Hit:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Get:3 http://repository.veeam.com/backup/linux/agent/dpkg/debian/public stable InRelease [7,549 B]
Hit:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease             
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nathan-renniewaldock/qdirstat/ubuntu yakkety InRelease
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease              
Hit:7 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease                
Get:8 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial InRelease [66.2 kB]    
Err:3 http://repository.veeam.com/backup/linux/agent/dpkg/debian/public stable InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3268CF038EEC045B
Fetched 73.8 kB in 1s (70.4 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://repository.veeam.com/backup/linux/agent/dpkg/debian/public stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3268CF038EEC045B
W: Failed to fetch http://repository.veeam.com/backup/linux/agent/dpkg/debian/public/dists/stable/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3268CF038EEC045B
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

myuser@myuser-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 3268CF038EEC045B
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.KcfykItU12/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 3268CF038EEC045B
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure
```

Comment: Lubuntu 16.10 cannot (realistically) be updated. You will want to perform a fresh install 

Comment: Sorry my mistake - lsb_release -a shows that it's currently on 18.04.6 LTS

Comment: ...is that "realistically" updatable?

Comment: FYI:  Lubuntu 18.04 LTS is no longer supported; refer https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/ or https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ where you'll note only Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop & Ubuntu Cloud come with 5 years of support; *flavors* had shorter lives. I'd suggest using `ubuntu-support-status` to assess the security status of your actual install. Your question is still on-topic here, but consider how much security matters to you and the results of prior command. You're now using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with LXDE (*not Lubuntu*).

Comment: Also please read the Lubuntu notes; Lubuntu 18.04 LTS was the end of the road for LXDE; and there were warnings found in subsequent release notes/announcements like found in https://lubuntu.me/focal-2-released/  "*Note, due to the extensive changes required for the shift in desktop environments, the Lubuntu team does not support upgrading from 18.04 or below to any greater release. Doing so will result in a broken system. If you are on 18.04 or below and would like to upgrade, please do a fresh install.*"  Your sources are a *mess* ! but having LXDE/Lubuntu on a server has too into the future

Comment: Assuming this is a Ubuntu Server where you added `lubuntu-desktop`, your base Ubuntu Server system will upgrade correctly & without issues.. it's the Lubuntu on top that may create issues, as upgrades will switch you to LXQt.  Personally I'd consider removing the `lubuntu-desktop` IF it's a server system then performing the *release-upgrade*, then add back whatever desktop you really want.  Yes I've *release-upgraded* many Lubuntu/LXDE systems without much hassle; but also had many that took hours of effort to correct so results are dependent on changes you've made; how stock is your system..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix the GPG error "NO\_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you have to create a snapshot of current system state using corresponding VirtualBox feature.
Then check all your repositories. They should contain at least the following lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list` for your actual Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS:

> ```
> deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
> deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
> deb http://gb.security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
> ```

You have to remove Docker's repository for *xenial*, it is not needed.

Then you have to add Veeam's key to the system:

```
cd /tmp
wget -c http://repository.veeam.com/keys/veeam.gpg
sudo apt-key add veeam.gpg
```

and update package lists and packages by

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude dist-upgrade
```

Then reboot and run `sudo do-release-upgrade` to upgrade the system to 20.04 LTS release.

Comment: Thanks - I managed to get past that stage using your instructions. Having rebooted, I'm now stuck trying to upgrade to the latest release (20.04.3). When I do "sudo do-release-upgrade" it keeps telling me "Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading". This is despite the fact that I had already done "sudo apt-get update" and rebooted. ????s

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install aptitude` and `sudo aptitude dist-upgrade` .